# How to find $f_{xy}$ if only $f_y$ and $f_x$ are given?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am given the partial derivative of a function $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is $4x^2-36$ and the partial derivative with respect to $y$ is $5y+20$. How to find $f_{xy}$ ?

Comment: Look up the definition of $F_{xy}$ and apply it.  Isn't it $F_{xy}=\frac {\partial F_x}{\partial y}$?  Presumably your function is $F(x,y)$.  $F \neq f$

Answer (score 0):

$f_x = 4x^2 - 36 \to f = \int f_xdx = \int (4x^2-36)dx = \dfrac{4x^3}{3} - 36x + C(y)\to f_y = C'(y) = 5y+20 \to C(y) = \int (5y+20)dy = \dfrac{5y^2}{2} + 20y + D$. Thus:

$f(x,y) = \dfrac{4x^3}{3} - 36x+\dfrac{5y^2}{2} + 20y + D$. Can you continue?